# why is method called upon new instance?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, this, es6-class

When `c1.rand` is called I'm not clear how the interpreter is able to access `this.num` because the constructor function hasn't been called yet. Shouldn't it have to call `constructor()` in rand in order to set the value for `this.num`?

```
class C {
    constructor() {
        this.num = Math.random();
    }
    rand() {
        console.log( "Random: " + this.num );
    }
}

var c1 = new C();
c1.rand(); // "Random: 0.4324299..." (any number from 0 to 1)
```

Comment: the constructor function is called on instantiation. no need for run it manually

Comment: @DayanMorenoLeon  Thanks. Is there something special about the word constructor?

Comment: @Gwater17— *constructor* is not a keyword or a reserved word. It is only special in that "*A constructor (also referred to as a constructor function) is a function object that supports the `[[Construct]]` internal method.*" (see [*ECMA-262 §6.1.7.2*](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/7.0/index.html#sec-object-internal-methods-and-internal-slots)). There is a constructor property of instances, but it's public and writeable, so not particularly useful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> When c1.rand is called I'm not clear how the interpreter is able to access this.num because the constructor function hasn't been called yet.

**Yes, it has**. You called the constructor when you wrote

```
var c1 = new C();
```

---

> Is only the constructor function called b/c constructor is a special keyword?

Yes, if a `class` has a `constructor` function defined it will be called when you invoke the class with the `new` keyword.

The `constructor` property is also accessible through the instance's prototype.

```
var c1 = new C();
c1.constructor === C //=> true
```

Comment: Is only the constructor function called b/c constructor is a special keyword?

Comment: lol @ the down-vote when this answer is identical to the up-voted answer – and submitted before it.

Comment: Actually I think you might need to rephrase the part about the constructor property. The constructor property is accessed on C through the prototype chain. see https://repl.it/DGoE

Comment: @Gwater17 my phrasing was hazardous. You are correct.

Comment: To be thorough, it is 'instance's prototype', not 'instance's `prototype`'. An instance doesn't have `prototype` property (it is `__proto__` or whatever, depending on the implementation).

Comment: @estus crazy how much room there is for ambiguity in these seemingly simple questions, eh ? thanks for review.

Comment: If anyone wants to put together a more definitive answer, I'm happy to withdraw this one. Tho, the more detailed we get, I suspect we'll be entering duplicate question/answer territory.

Answer (score 4):

Constructors are immediately called when an object is created, so when you call:

```
var c1 = new C();
```

The constructor is called. The name constructor comes from the use, it is immediately invoked because *it constructs the object.* This means it initializes variables, etc - things essential to the object, `this.num` in your case. And yes, it is a reserved function for object creation when a class is declared.

The `new` keyword is saying 'new instance' and on new instance creation, the constructor is called.